# arterySignalIr/Ping - O que está gerando esse erro?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, signalr

O projeto `MVC` em `C#` aqui da empresa está com um bug muito bizarro, pra dizer o mínimo. De tempos em tempos estoura um erro aleatório:

The controller for path ...arterySignalIr/Ping was not found or does not implement IController, vide imagem abaixo:

[image: The controller for path ...arterySignalIr/Ping was not found or does not implement IController.]

Atualmente no módulo que eu estou trabalhando ele fica estourando erro aleatoriamente a cada mais ou menos 3 minutos. O estranho é que não cai a sessão nem quebra nada, ele simplesmente fica estourando erro.

Minha dúvida é se vocês sabem que erro é esse?

É uma DLL que causa isso? Qual?

Como consertar isso?

Comment: DLLs são *contairners* de códigos, então de uma certa forma é, e não é. Isto não tem a menor importância. Precisa saber onde, no código, está causando isto. Só com estas informações não dá para saber. Manda imprimir o *stack trace* da exceção. As coisas não podem acontecer de forma tão aleatória. E a pior coisa que pode fazer e parece que está fazendo é tentar esconder o erro. E se não estivesse fazendo isto seria mais fácil identificar o que está causando.Hoje a exceção é o recurso mais mal usado das linguagens.Está causando mais mal do que bem.Lançam o que não devem e capturam o que não pode

Comment: assim que estourar o erro novamente eu edito e mando, eu realmente estou bem perdido em entender isso esse erro.....

Comment: Não, isto é programar por coincidência. Tem que descobrir onde está gerando o erro agora!. Tem que usar um método científico. Se está difícil achar o erro é porque ele é mais grave do que parece.

Comment: ai que está parceiro, ninguem conseguiu descobrir o que está gerando o erro, nem o programador com um milhao de certificações achou o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Tentou, pelo menos, olhar o stacktrace e ver em que local o erro está estourando? Já é um começo

Comment: eu vim pro stack overflow tentar ver se alguem conhecia esse problema exatamente pela dificuldade de conseguir rastrear o problema, mas enfim, tanto faz. O Felipe ali já conseguiu resolver meu problema

Comment: Optei por reabrir a pergunta já que o foi possível respondê-la de forma objetiva somente com as informações disponibilizadas pelo seu autor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este erro acontece somente em modo ´Debug´ por causa do recurso `Browser Link`do Visual Studio, você pode optar pelas seguintes opções para resolver seu problema:

**Desativar o Browser Link:** (Recomendado se você não faz uso do recurso)
Para tal basta adicionar a seguinte chave no bloco appSettings do seu webconfig

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

**Se você realmente faz questão do recurso** mas e não quer sofrer com as missing controller exceptions, basta ignorar as rotas do `Browser Link` editando suas configurações de rotas conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

#if DEBUG
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*browserlink}", new { browserlink = @".*/arterySignalR/ping" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*browserlink}", new { browserlink = @".*__browserLink.*" });
#endif

    //...Outras rotas
}
```

Obs: como o bloco de ignore está dentro de um pragma debug este tratamento só vai ocorrer quando você estiver debugando que é exatamente quando o recurso Browser Link está em atividade.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda parceiro!

Comment: De nada precisando a comunidade está ai para ajudar.